# jquery ui datepicker Internet explorer css issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I've been using the jquery ui datepicker as an event calendar and it works great in Firefox and Chrome. However, it does not work correctly in IE 8 and 9.

What should happen is the selected dates should be highlighted when viewing the calendar. However, in IE 8 and 9 the days are only highlighted when a user clicks on them, rather than being highlighted from the start

heres a link to it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/GmPcC/3/ (ignore the text colour)

Javascript:

```
    var events = [ 
    { Title: "Event1", Date: new Date("06/13/2013") }, 
    { Title: "even2", Date: new Date("06/25/2013") }, 
    { Title: "event3", Date: new Date("06/22/2013") }
    ];$("div").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var result = [true, '', null];
            var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
                return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
        });

        if (matching.length) {
            result = [true, 'highlight', null];
        }
        return result;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var date,
            selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
            i = 0,
            event = null;

        while (i < events.length && !event) {
            date = events[i].Date;

            if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                event = events[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (event) {
            alert(event.Title);
        }
    }
});
```

Hopefully someone can help.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its more of a css problem.

Try adding

```
filter:none !important; to table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.highlight > a
```